# Как развернуть Rest Api

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

Есть готовое апи и есть сервер, но я никак не могу понять, как же его развернуть, ip статический, не могу найти никакой информации

Comment: Что именно не получается? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/hello-world-tutorial/run